# HTTP request to fetch video returning 200 status code also and Parse error also in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, request

I am trying to download video from some URL it is downloading video but also returning Parse Error so callback happening two times.

```
http.get(url, function(response) {
        console.log("url "+url)
        console.log("Got response: " + response.statusCode);
        if(response && response.statusCode == 200){//OK
            mkdirp(dest,function(err){ 
                if(err){
                      console.log("err "+err);
                }else{ //create path dynamically
                    console.log("else SUCCESS")
                    var file = fs.createWriteStream("/mydrive/test.flv");
                    response.pipe(file);
                    file.on('finish', function() {
                        //console.log("finish file creation....")
                      file.close();
                    });
                } 
             });  
        }else{
           console.log("No video "+response.statusCode);
        }         
 }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
 });
```

Output what I am getting is so callback is happening two times.

I want either response or failure callback:

```
Got response: 200

Got error: Parse Error
```

Comment: Callback does not return any other parameters as error and so on?? just one parameter `response`?

Comment: @Saeed.At the callback of `http.get` is invoked with a single argument [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)